# Why am I getting these runtime errors? Cannot connect to database (Netbeans with sql db)

Tags: sql-server, netbeans

Ok,

1. The database is present. I have successfully run the sql query file.
2. I have included the bin.jar reference library to connect to the db.

When I run the program i get:

Cannot connect to database server

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at DBControl.getAllIndredients(DBControl.java:29)
        at Main.initFromDB(Main.java:207)
        at Main.<init>(Main.java:184)
        at Main$4.run(Main.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Can someone construe from this or have any ideas why I can't connect to the db server?

Answer (score 0):

A NULL Pointer exception means that a reference has not been initialized. Did you forget to call "New" on something? You probably need a db connection object instance of some sort.